# How to use f'string bytes'string together?

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

It seems that python allow to combine r'string and b'string together.
But not f'string and b'string !

classic usage:

```
>>> name='john'
>>> print(f'hello {name}')
hello john
```

with bytes and f'string:

Try 1:

```
>>> name=b'john'
>>> print(fb'hello {name}')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(fb'hello {name}')
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Try 2:

```
>>> print(f'hello {name}')
hello b'john'
```

So it seems that I need to perform 2 extra computation per lines

1. bin -> ascii
2. f'string
3. ascii -> bin

Is there a better approach ?
Is it possible to combine f'string with bytes'string ?

Thanks
best regards

Comment: You can use `b'hello ' + name`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, yes it is the same problem. In short, that tells "is not yet supported"